# Starting a program in a bat file using the Path variable

Tags: windows-7, batch, path, console

I often use a command line application. Its path is defined in the environment options, so in the `PATH` variable. When I manually launch the console and if I type the program name, it's launched.

For example, I type `theprogram -option1 -option2` then it's launched with whatever the working directory is. (the `.exe` path is resolved by the `PATH` environment).

If I write the same in a `.bat` file, Windows brings up a message box saying it cannot find the program. In the `.bat` file there is `start theprogram -option1 -option2`, but I get the error message. So it seems that the `PATH` variable is not used in a `.bat`/`.cmd` file.

How can I launch `theprogram` from a `.bat` file, without specifying the full path? Does Windows 7 disable the `PATH` variable in `.bat`/`.cmd` files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this all the time on Windows 7 without any problems. Try leaving out the 'start' instruction and just run the program in the batch file using the program name directly, e.g.

```
theprogram -option1 -option2
```

don't forget to use quotes if there is a space in the name or path, e.g.

```
"the program" -option1 -option2
```

If that still doesn't work try running a very simple batch file to check your environment vars are loading correctly, e.g. save this as a batch file and run it:

```
set
pause
```

Comment: The OP states in his question that be has already tried this.

Comment: @Dennis not from my reading of the question. He uses 'start' to run the program not just the program name. I've expanded the answer a little.

Comment: Yes *snwodude*, it's true, but actually now it's working. I thing that's because I've reboot since it was failling...The PC involved is running 24/24.Maybe there is s a kind of limitation when modfying the PATH variable: you can use it directly in a console but you must reboot to get the new PATH item handled in bat files ? Anyway it's OK now.

Comment: > I type **theprogram -option1 -option2** then it's launched whatever the working dir is. [...] If I write the same in a bat file, Windows bangs a messagebox saying it cannot find the program.

Comment: It's OK *Dennis*, it seems that the problem was caused because the system was not rebooted after the PATH modification...

Comment: @Kloze: Yes and no. Changes to environment variables only affect *new* processes, not *already running* ones. (Exception being the Windows GUI itself, since it actively monitors for changes.) So you would need to log out, or at least close all programs and reopen them